# Can My Personal GMail Query A Remote LDAP Server?

Tags: ldap, gmail

I have a personal GMail account, from which I frequently send e-mail to a great many various users of a specific business. The corporation has been kind enough to provide me with the credentials to access their LDAP server, with which I would like my GMail web client to be able to auto-complete partial addresses or names for which that LDAP server has an entry.

Is there any way I can get a personal GMail account (or it's corresponding entire Google account) account to incorporate an LDAP server into it's Contacts?

If I cannot get it to query dynamically and on-demand, is there an idiot-proof way (assuming the client permits, which they may not) to query the LDAP server for it's entire database, save it, and bulk import it to GMail? Perhaps, even, something I could set to repeat periodically (weekly, perhaps), without human interaction?

If I did the latter, I assume it would be trivial to import all of these contacts under a single category that could be easily manipulated from within the GMail web-based client.

I have been a staunch user and supporter of the GMail web-based client since it's instantiation, but this one is kind of a deal-breaker for me. If it's impossible, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: I really doubt this can be done but don't you think you should be asking GMail support about this?

Comment: How can this be a deal-breaker if you've never had it before? Also, I don't think that yourself and Google have a contract that you can even have a deal breaker over

Comment: Developing a program to periodically sync your Google contacts with the LDAP server would be possible if you are a programmer.  I haven't seen anything generic, but there are lots of hits about accessing the Contacts API.  Your best might be to try and find a **browser-based** ldap extension.  That way you could use the ldap contacts anywhere.

Comment: @Farseeker I've been using the GMail web-client for a long time, never before needing to abandon it in favor of a fat client like Thunderbird. And if I can't do this thing, I'm going to end up doing exactly that. That's all I intended to express when I said "deal-breaker". Perhaps I chose my words poorly.

Comment: I reopened this question because it was closed on all trilogy sites. I think it should get a chance here on Serverfault. Also, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47028/where-does-this-question-belong

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a specific product that will do this for you, but I can envisage the rough process you'll need to go through:

1. Extract the user SMTP addresses & Names from LDAP. This is most certainly possible and you probably want to try and get it into a CSV format. You could do this with VBScript (check [this](https://exchangepedia.com/blog/2005/09/how-to-export-all-email-addresses-from.html) out) or perhaps PowerShell (see [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_qad_export_csv.htm)).
2. Transform this into a suitable format for GMail contacts. Since GMail accepts CSV, you might be able to do this with no or minimal alteration to your export data. Here's the skinny on GMail's [acceptable CSV format](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12119).
3. Load your data into GMail.

Once you've figured out your tool chain/process for this, you may find you can schedule it to run without your intervention. I would imagine many other people would be very interested in a writeup, too!

Comment: I'm sure you can NOT set up sync with the LDAP on regular free gmail.

I though you should be able to with Google Apps (paid gmail etc), but the only solutions seem to offer user and group sync, not pure contacts sync.

I would recommend you try to follow Chris Thorpe's instructions. (+1). And I too think this would be of interest to others.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the GMail Contacts API v3 and a script to import the database onto your GMail contacts (presumably a group), which would allow you to essentially transfer all the contacts over.